# Python requirements.txt that shows which package installed which?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I recently saw a python requirements.txt file with entries that look like this:

```
hyper==15.2.1              # via twisted
iddna==1.5                 # via cryptography, requests
```

In other words, it identifies which package was responsible for installing another as a dependency. I'm wondering if there's a tool out there that I don't know about or if the author has added the comments manually. Or is there a secret option for pip freeze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These comments that were added to the `requirements.txt` are not generated from a `pip freeze` option ([pip freeze docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/)). They most likely come from [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools). From the README, the `pip-compile` command will produce a `requirements.txt` with those comments showing the parent dependency. Hope this helps.